# django registration redux database extension

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-admin

I'm building a web page with multiple apps... I'm using django registration redux for user management, and I have another app `monitor` which has another database. I am looking to connect user table from `redux` to company table from the `monitor` app, so a Company can have multiple users - so I need an extra field in the `user` table to use as foreign key to the `company` table => One `company` can have many `users`.

My understanding is that to extand `user` table from redux I just need to create a one-to-one field in my employee table and add all the fields I want.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

My problems:

1. I don't think this is working, I think it's very wrong and I'm not sure where to look for help
2. I would like to create a dummy company when the user is first created, so the company field in the employee table is always populated? Or is there a better approach to user-company connection?

Hope this is not too confusing...

Answer (score 0):

One way to always have a default dummy company, under your model code:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyThing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.company:
        dummy_company = Company(name='Microsoft').save()
        self.company = dummy_company
        super(MyThing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```